# find list using createcriteria nested object property

Tags: grails, where-clause

I have a domain like this

```
 Employee {
   Address address
   String name
   String title
}
```

and another domain

```
 Address {
  String country
  String locality 
  String city
}
```

and now i want to find the all the employee with given city something like that i tried

```
  def employees = Employee.where { 
      address {
       city == params.city
        }
   }
```

but this is not working , how can i achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like following

```
List<Employee> employees=Employee.createCriteria().list{
    'address'{
         eq('city',params.city)
     }

}
```

Note: When the `eq('city',city)` (same parameter name) is used, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for accessing properties of associations differs between criteria and where queries.

## Where query

```
def employees = Employee.where { 
  address.city == params.city
}
```

See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries

## Criteria query

```
def employees = Employee.withCriteria {
    address {
        eq('city', params.city)
    }
}
```

See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria